# Filtering a visual based on number of values selected in slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a few visuals on my report that I only want to display when just one value is selected in the sliced column. I attempted to do this by creating a measure to evaluate the number of selections in the sliced column, and then used this measure as a filter in my visual. The measures I've attempted are the following:

```
SlicerCheck =   if(calculate(distinctcount([SlicerColumn]),allselected([SlicerColumn]))=1,"Y","N") 
//I set the visual filter to "is Y" in this case
```

And

```
SlicerCheck = If(HASONEVALUE('Master File'[Custom]),1)
//I set the visual filter to "is 1"
```

However, as seen in the attached image (based on the second measure above) [Slicer Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C46Co.jpg), the visual on the top right hand side still has a display even though the SlicerCheck is blank. This is also an issue when all the values are selected in the slicer, before a filter selection is made.

Please let me know if there is a solution to this, or if I'm making a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the desired outcome by using the HASONEFILTER function instead of HASONEVALUE.